# Issues using smartpointers for sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, smart-pointers

First off I'm sorry before hand if my code is just awful and confusing. That said I've been working on a project for school and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. It has to do with me feeding the original array into a smart pointer vector. If I need to post all the code I will but I am going to try and just share the code that seems relevant.

Below is all of the class definitions etc.

```
template <typename T>
class sptr {
public:
    sptr(T *_ptr=NULL) { ptr = _ptr;}

    bool operator < (const sptr &rhs) const
    {   return *ptr < *rhs.ptr;}

private:
    T *ptr;

};

template <class T>
class slist {
  private:
    struct node {
      node() { data=T(); next=NULL; }
      // add overloaded operator< code
      bool operator<(node rhs){
          if(data < rhs.data)
              return true;
          return false;
      }
      T data;
      node *next;
    };

  public:
    class iterator {
    public:
      iterator() : p(NULL) {}
      T & operator*() { return p->data; }
      iterator & operator++() { p = p->next; return *this; }
      bool operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const { return p != rhs.p; }

    private:
      friend class slist<T>;
      iterator(node *p) : p(p) {}
      node *p;
    };

  public:
    slist();
    ~slist();

    void push_back(const T &);
    void sort();

    iterator begin() { return iterator(head->next); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(NULL); }
    int N;

  private:
    node *head;
    node *tail;
};
```

Here is the actual sort code

```
void slist<T>::sort()
{
  // set up smart point array for list
    vector<sptr<node> > Ap(N);
    iterator it;
    node *temp = head->next;

    // Couldnt figure out syntax of assigning values to the array

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        sptr<node> temp2(*temp);
        Ap[i] = temp2;
        temp = temp->next;
    }


  // apply std::sort
    std::sort(Ap.begin(), Ap.end());
  // relink linked list using sort result
    node *ptr = head->next;
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++){
        ptr = Ap[i];
        ptr -> next = Ap[i+1];
    }

}
```

The for loop under the comment about not being able to figure out syntax is the main area of issue. When I try to compile I get a mess of an error statement. The error output is below.

```
sort3b.cpp: In member function 'void slist<T>::sort() [with T = record]':
sort3b.cpp:217:18:   instantiated from here
sort3b.cpp:166:25: error: no matching function for call to 'sptr<slist<record>::node>::sptr(slist<record>::node&)'
sort3b.cpp:166:25: note: candidates are:
sort3b.cpp:69:2: note: sptr<T>::sptr(T*) [with T = slist<record>::node]
sort3b.cpp:69:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'slist<record>::node' to 'slist<record>::node*'
sort3b.cpp:67:7: note: sptr<slist<record>::node>::sptr(const sptr<slist<record>::node>&)
sort3b.cpp:67:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'slist<record>::node' to 'const sptr<slist<record>                                                                                                                          ::node>&'
sort3b.cpp:217:18:   instantiated from here
sort3b.cpp:177:3: error: cannot convert 'sptr<slist<record>::node>' to 'slist<record>::node*' in assignment
sort3b.cpp:178:3: error: cannot convert 'sptr<slist<record>::node>' to 'slist<record>::node*' in assignment
make: *** [sort3b] Error 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Knowing me its probably something thats really simple. I know it has something to do with feeding the data into the vector of smart pointers but I am just completely stuck.

New error message after I stopped referencing temp.

```
sort3b.cpp: In member function 'void slist<T>::sort() [with T = record]':
sort3b.cpp:217:18:   instantiated from here
sort3b.cpp:177:3: error: cannot convert 'sptr<slist<record>::node>' to 'slist<record>::node*' in assignment
sort3b.cpp:178:3: error: cannot convert 'sptr<slist<record>::node>' to 'slist<record>::node*' in assignment
```

Here its going to be a similar issue but I am still stuck. I feel pretty dumb.

Comment: By the way, you are trying to sort a linked list that performs very badly. Use an array list to implement your sorting algorithm to have better performance. Think on how to avoid to use a vector because it adds an extra overhead into your algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the key to horrible C++ error messages is to look at what it's trying to convert to what. Here it's trying first to convert a `node` to a `node*`. That means it's looking for a pointer but you're not giving it one.

So stop de-referencing `temp`.

Comment: Thanks That helped but Now I am getting a new similar message. I tried dereferencing the A[i] type array but that didnt do it either.

Comment: Again, look at what it's trying to convert to what (and what line it's happening at).  The error message you're getting is telling you exactly what the problem is.